# data table unable to display the field of related object in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, datatables.js

I have a data table which displays `Name` field and `Address` field(`Address` related to another object).The `Name` field is displayed properly but if I iterate over the list in html for `pcon.Address__r.Name` it gives error. If only `pcon.Address__r` is given, it shows `[object object]` in table. Can anybody resolve this issue. thank you in advance.

html

```html
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="background-color: #151963;color: white;">Name</th>
                <th style="background-color: #151963;color: white;">Address</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <template for:each={pconfig} for:item="pcon" for:index="i">
                <tr class={pcon.row} data-id={pcon.Id} data-index={i} key={pcon.Id} onclick{getquotes} >
                    <td>{pcon.Name}</td>
                    <td>{pcon.Address__r.Name}</td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</lightning-layout-item>
```

Js:

```javascript
@wire(Vendor_getProduct,{ basketId: 'fef0E0000dwedjh' })
    getProducts({error,data})
    {
         if(data)
         {
            //console.log( 'Fetched Data ' + JSON.stringify( data ) );
            this.pconfig =  JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( data) );
            console.log('products are:',data);
         }
         else if(error){
            this.error=data;
            console.log('error is undefined');
         } 
    }
```

apex class:

```apex
public class c {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Product_Configuration__c> getProduct (Id basketId) {
        return [select  id, 
                        name, 
                        Address__r.name, 
                from  Product_Configuration__c
 where Product_Basket__c =:basketId];
    }
```

Comment: What is the output of this log? console.log('products are:',data);

Comment: i saw some mistake in above code like in apex remove comma after Address__r.name and in html write method in quotes onclick{getquotes}

Comment: Address__c: 
"a3d0E000002p8eZQAQ"
Address__r: 
Id: "a3d0E000002p8eZQAQ"
Name: "Test account 1"
[[Prototype]]: 
Object
Bandwidth__c: 40
CurrencyIsoCode: "USD"
Id: "a3J0E0000017WwcUAE"
Name: "Big Blue"
Service_Bandwidth__c: 40
cscfga__Product_Basket__c: "a3G0E000001Ui6rUAC"
[[Prototype]]
: 
I need to print address name i.e Test account 1

Answer (score 1):

in js do not need to parse or stringify

use track decorator to define the variable like this
@track pconfig = [];

this will resolve your problem

js :

```
@wire(Vendor_getProduct,{ basketId: '0032w000006LmH9AAK' })
    getProducts({error,data})
    {
         if(data){ 
            this.pconfig = data;
            console.log(this.pconfig)
        }
        if(error){
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Karan Sharama , I have tried the way you had shared. even that doesnt work

Comment: can you show me the error.

Comment: [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')] is the error